# Seed Parse Local Data Store

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

I have a few objects I already created on Parse. I want to take those 10 objects and seed them on first app launch to the `Local Data Store` (Android + iOS) so that the user can see the data if there is no connectivity.

I created a plist with the objectIds and properties and loop through it on app launch. I create the objects with: `objectWithoutDataWithObjectId` and then set the properties and pin the object. The pin does not work as I query them with empty results.

Any suggestions?